# How to use key-Value pairs in ng-select in angular 8

Tags: dropdown, angular8, angular-ngselect

I want to display a dropdown for a key-value pair array. It should display values with bindLabel as the value and the value binded that is bindValue should be the key.

For example : if array is:

```
Array= {
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value2",
   .
   .
   .
"key3":"value3"

}
```

the dropdown should be displayed as value1, value2 , value3 and so on. And if we select value1, the binded value should be key1.

I am using :

```
<ng-select [items]="Array" [searchable]="true" >
  <ng-option [value]="">Select</ng-option>
</ng-select>
```

It is showing error as: ERROR TypeError: items.map is not a function.

I want to do this using ng-select. Is it possible to achieve this .

Comment: I have gone through the similar issue and found solution from here: https://stackblitz.com/run?file=src%2Fdata-source-options-example.component.ts

Answer (score 2):

Use keyvalue pipe

```
<ng-select [items]="Array | keyvalue" [bindValue]="'key'" [bindLabel]="'value'" [searchable]="true"></ng-select>
```